# can't find pixel effect in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, filter

hi everyone please help!
what effect in this pictures that does flat merged round pixels? saw it many times but cant find the way to do it

[image]

Comment: This is a complex image. All those colored dots contain tens or hundreds actual image pixels. It would take a long time to make a replica from scratch, maybe a week, if one happened to make only lucky guesses. You should show exactly which dots you want. If you want a receipe for all of them, your question would be closed soon.

Comment: okay i think this images describe my question clearly.
actually it something that happens when you gaussian blur vector and treshold but as i remember there is proper filter for this....... 
[link1](https://i0.wp.com/unitycoder.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/pixel_rounded_edges_shader.jpg)
[link2](https://previews.123rf.com/images/supertrooper/supertrooper1712/supertrooper171200289/91131168-raster-of-pixel-art-with-abstract-background-made-of-geometric-shapes-rounded-pixel-effect-8-bit-des.jpg)

Comment: Gaussian coupled with treshold. Or grow and shrink

Comment: Questions that ask, "What button do I click to make this complex artwork with no effort?" are hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method. This is not an exact copy, just a way to get something kind of similar

Take an ordinary photograph with plenty of detail. Change the mode to Greyscale, then convert to Bitmap, and choose to convert to a halftone. Set the frequency low, something like 10, to make the halftone dots big.

Zoom in on an interesting part of the image that has plenty of variation, and crop it.

Something like this

[image]

Change from Bitmap mode to Greyscale, then back to RGB.

Scale the image up, say around 2000px x 2000px, Resampling on, set the interpolation to "Preserve Details (enlargement)".

Do *Filter > Other > Highpass*, and change the slider until you get something that looks like this, with light and dark halos around the dots

[image]

Then add several Curves adjustments and set up some random RGB curves on each. Paint in black on each mask in different areas.

An example

[image]

Anyway, here's the finished result. Obviously you can take lots more time and care. I just did this very quickly as an example.

[image]

You could also take this further and copy and paste various pieces of haltones, above the background layer, to get a more random look

**Edit:** My halftone dots weren't very smooth so here's another attempt with the same basic technique. This time I used a lower frequency to get bigger dots. Blurred it, then did a Threshold. I also added an extra blurred duplicate of the background and set to subtract. You could add lots more variation, more layers, different blend modes etc.

[image]

This one using a colour burn blend mode on the blurred copy

[image]

Comment: hi! thank u very much for your answer but it is not the exact thing i'm looking for. i want to achieve the form of smooth round pixel (as i remember there is certain filter for this but i can't find it) [link2](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/rounded-flow-squares-pixelated-effect-260nw-758375629.jpg)

Comment: @desperate-anna Yeah, you could do this by making the half-tone dots bigger to begin with, that will make them look smoother, perhaps use a larger image than I did. Again this is just a very rough example.

Comment: ..maybe.. [Filter > Other > Min then Filter > Other > Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYfCm.gif) and proceed with find edges?? The min/max will round things. Really just guessing though.

Comment: @desperate-anna here's another [example](https://imgur.com/i5pn76W) same technique basically, but bigger halftone dots (lower frequency). I blurred them to smooth them, and added a threshold adjustment. Added a duplicate of the background layer and blurred it to get more outline variation and set it to blend mode Subtract.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing what's common in your example image and in the couple of links that you inserted to your comment below the question I guess that you want to round rectangular  corners. And you want it in Photoshop, not in Illustrator (see NOTE1).

[image]

Here I drew a few black (bitmap) shapes on a layer. I made a duplicate and merged it with a white layer for actual filtering, the black originals stayed  available in case some tests were needed.

Filter Noise > Median was applied to blunt the sharp corners and to build bridges between close corners. Good radius depends the pixel dimensions of the shapes:

[image]

It's not round, but it comes better by applying the same filtering again:

[image]

I selected the white with the magic wand and deleted it. Then I inverted the selection and filled the areas with solid blue:

[image]

Another way is to select the rectangular areas and smooth the selection with Refine Edge. Invert the selection and delete the exterior. You may need to repeat the process because the selection smoothing affects too little.

NOTE1: The about same shapes have got corner rounding effect in Illustrator:

[image]

Bridges are generated if the squares slightly overlap (enlargened with Transform Each > Scale ) and they are united to one before rounding:

[image]